# Get a dynamic range of a column in a table

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to find a way of getting a range from of a table for certain column dynamically. By this I mean getting the first row and finding the end row (keep in mind I need to find the end row dynamically).

Something similar to using

```
.End(xlUp).Row
```

but for a Table column instead.

Comment: Do you need the **header row** in the range ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A table will be a member of the worksheet's `ListObjects` collection. You can do something like this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim table As ListObject
    Set table = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    Debug.Print table.ListColumns(2).Range.Rows.Count
End Sub
```

Note that `ListObjects` have a `ListColumns` collection whose entries can be turned into ranges.

The following documentation is helpful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff839458.aspx . See also this tutorial:
 http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables